# How do I avoid repeating column names in a csv file in r?

Tags: r

I have a csv file from which I have to copy some rows in another csv file. However, I want only the first row to have column names and rest of the rows should not have any column names. following is the code attached. The following code gives me column names prior to every row.

```
for(f in 1:length(file$mismatches)){
  if((file$mismatches[f]==0)==T ){ 
    write.table(x=file[f,], append = T, file = paste0('0_mismatches','.csv'),sep=",",col.names=c('organism_name_spacer','organism_spacer_accession_number','organism_spacer_id','organism_name_protospacer','organism_protospacer_accession_number','spacer_sequence','protospacer_sequence','mismatches'),row.names = F)

  }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to do this

Comment: I have a csv file let's say test. One of the column is named as mismatches. I want to get all the rows which have identical mismatches together into another csv file. To the new csv file I want to assign column names, but the column names should be such that they occur only once at the top and not prior to every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all files have the same column names, in the same order, you can do something like:

```
require(tidyverse)
files_to_load <- {list of file paths to load}
df <- data_frame(filename = files_to_load)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(data = map(filename, read_csv, [other arguments to read_csv]))  
dfs_as_list <- pull(df, data)
dfs_as_single_df <- bind_rows(dfs_as_list)
```

Not tried this as the example you've given isn't reproducible, so you'll need to adapt.

The `pull` function extracts data, a list column, to produce a list of data_frames.

`bind_rows` accepts a list of data_frames as a single output, and tries to join them.

The other arguments to `read_csv` would likely include an argument to `col_types` so that the column types are consistent in all data_frames to join.